# zfdatagrid - Plugin by name 'Table' was not found in the registry;

Tags: zend-framework, zfdatagrid

I've just installed the library and tried a simple table with an array

```
$grid = Bvb_Grid::factory("Bvb_Grid_Deploy_Table");
$grid->setSource(new Bvb_Grid_Source_Array($this->pkg));
$myGrid = $grid->deploy();
```

I get this error:

**`Plugin by name 'Table' was not found in the registry; used paths: Bvb_Grid_Template_: Bvb/Grid/Template/`**

I'm not familiar with how this works, but would guess looking at the error that it looks in the `Bvb/Grid/Template/` directory, there is a `Table.php` in there with the class `Bvb_Grid_Template_Table`.Thank you.

Comment: There are a few people with this problem on the zfdatagrid site so could be a bug, doesn't look like it's going to be fixed...

Answer (score 0):

Try a little bit different. Write "Table" instead of "Bvb_Grid_Deploy_Table". In my example there is also grid configuration file...

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../configs/grid.ini','clients');
$grid = Bvb_Grid::factory('Table', $config);
$model = new Sand_Model_DbTable_Asset();
$source = new Bvb_Grid_Source_Zend_Table($model);
$grid->setSource($source);
/*
   more code here...
*/
$myGrid = $grid->deploy();
$this->view->grid = $myGrid;
```